# passing a argument of a function

Tags: r, function

I have a function declared as shown below.

```
asd <- function(a,b){
  c <- a + b
  return(c)
}
```

Now, I pass arguments to function

```
asd(3,4)
7
```

When I pass `args(asd)` I get as `a, b`

Is there a way to get what i have declared. In this case it is 3,4 so I need to see 3 and 4 . Is this possible?

Comment: But if you do `args(asd)` you _haven't_ passed `3, 4`. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: It's not clear to me either what exactly you are trying to do. When and where exactly are you trying to capture these arguments? What's the desired behavior here?

Comment: Thanks all for the time. I need to see what all arguments is been passed to the function asd? Can we capture this. Say, first time the user passes 3,4 and next time, he passes, 4,5 . Both these (3,4 and 4,5 ) should be the output. Makes sense?

Comment: So you want the function to have a memory of all the values what were passed to it? In that case you way want to create a closure that returns a function so you have an environment to track those values. But without a clear example of what behavior you need from this function, it's not clear what code you would need exactly. At least show the desired behavior of the function even if you can't write the source of the function yourself.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the time. I have briefed in this link, I have tried hard to  frame and explain the issue here. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61299331/understanding-the-structure-and-dependencies-of-my-application